# No text is shown on terminal when hitting a breakpoint when using Guard

Tags: guard

I add a `binding.pry` or a `byebug` on a line and save and guard starts fine.

But when it hits the breakpoint, nothing I type comes out on the terminal.

Using rspec on the file works fine.

Using

- ruby 3.0.5
- Rails 6.1.7.6
- guard 2.18.0

Answer (score 0):

Use `.reset` when in a Guard prompt.